# no suitable node - unable to deploy image using docker service

Tags: docker, arm, raspberry-pi3, docker-swarm

I  have a docker swarm based on raspberry pi 3. I have 3 nodes. I have created an image on my laptop and pushed that to the docker registry.

If I try to start the image on a node in the swarm using docker run it works as expected.

```
docker run -ti alexellis2/pi-sharp:0.1
```

but if i try and start it using a docker service it fails.

```
docker service create --name test alexellis2/pi-sharp:0.1
```

Error
     1/1: no suitable node (unsupported platform on 3 nodes)

If I do an docker inspect on the service it shows this information.

```
"Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

I have tried to prune containers and images to no avail.

My question is why am I able to use the image using docker run but not using docker service?

Comment: if I build the docker image on the raspberry pi everything works. Strange thing is the Platform property does not contain an architecture attribute.

Comment: Wondering if there is a solution for running images built on the Docker Hub (x86) with qemu? `docker run ...` works, but `docker service create ...` does not. Maybe there is a way to specify the architecture attribute if an image is run on a different platform than the build environment?

Answer (score 4):

when you build your in PC, the build environment is **x86**.
if you build the image on the Pi, the build environment and architecture is **armhf**.

Those images are not cross-platform and this is known problem nowadays.
https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/2017/07/27/create-multi-architecture-docker-image/

you might be right that in some scenarios, docker run versus docker service might work strangely (docker service results in error state, docker run works)

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue with resolving images by docker.
When I type

> docker info

In one of lines I see:

```
Architecture: armv7l
```

But when I build image on the same machine. And then inspect image,

> docker image inspect 7c2f63598729

In one of lines what do I see:

```
"io.resin.architecture": "armhf",
```

How is this even possible ?
The issue was resolved, by adding to stack command additional argument

> --resolve-image never

So now, my stack deploy looks like this

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml --resolve-image never home
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the image directly on the pi, you have definitely compiled it for the right architecture. If it cannot run using docker swarm, try to recreate the stack.

I accidentally pulled an x86 image to the pi, and even after downloading a new arm-compatible image from the registry, I was still getting:

```
no suitable node (unsupported platform on 3 nodes)
```

Doing docker inspect on the stack I could see this:

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
"OS": "linux"
```

After recreating the stack it started up correctly. Docker inspect on the stack no longer has any indication of architecture.